# Problemas al tratar de concatenar nueva información a un div con innerHtml me dice lo siguiente: the contents are not literal

Tags: c#, html5

Al momento de querer agregar una nueva section a un div ya existente me sale el siguiente error:

```
 Cannot get inner content of because the contents are not literal.
```

El código es el siguiente:

```
RowsAdd = "<section class='col-lg-12 text-center top-buffer'><section class='col-lg-2'> <label>Titulo</label></section><section class='col-lg-2'><label>Descripcion</label></section><section class='col-lg-2'><label>Horas</label></section><section class='col-lg-2'><label>Seccion</label></section><section class='col-lg-1'><label>Hecho</label></section></section><section class='col-lg-12 text-center top-buffer'><section class='col-lg-2'><input type='text' class='form-control mandatory'/> </section><section class='col-lg-2'><textarea rows='5' class='form-control mandatory'></textarea></section> <section class='col-lg-2' > <input type='number' class='form-control mandatory'/> </section> <section class='col-lg-2' > <input type='text' class='form-control mandatory'/> </section> <section class='col-lg-1' > <input type='checkbox' class='form-control mandatory'/> </section> <section class='col-lg-2' > <button class='btn btn-primary' style='margin-top: 0px; ' runat='server' ID='addRow' OnServerClick='addRow_OnServerClick'> Agregar </button> </section> <section class='col-lg-1' > <button class='btn btn-primary' style='margin-top: 0px; '> Remover </button> </section> </section><span>&nbsp;</span>";
    contantRows.InnerHtml += RowsAdd;
```

Si cambio el signo `+=` por un simple `=` si funciona pero me reemplaza el contenido asi que necesito que se concatene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso es por que tu contenido que esta en `RowsAdd` no es literal, para que lo sea, no debe haber ningún control o control del servidor `runat="server"` dentro que requiera representación

Para mas información sobre esto puedes revisar esta [publicación](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610249/cannot-get-inner-content-of-because-the-contents-are-not-literal)